# MSSQL в Oracle через Openquery: проблемы с кодировкой

Tags: sql-server, кодировка, oracle

Есть оракловая база.
В MSSQL, через openquery выполняем запрос к этой базе.
Запрос выполняется, но кириллица приходит в виде `²�·²À°Â` (в оригинале это "возврат")
Собственно, вопрос: где и что настраивать? В параметрах запроса? В параметрах подключения? В параметрах сервера (если да - то какого?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблему решил.
На стороне оракла кодировка `ISO8859-5`.
Сперва переводим в `1251`:

```
convert(Name, ''CL8MSWIN1251'', ''CL8ISO8859P5'')
```

Потом переводим в `RAW`, чтобы обмениваться бинарными данными и не полагаться на причуды провайдеров (в моем случае такие причуды были и простая конвертация ничего не давала):

```
utl_raw.cast_to_raw(convert(Name, ''CL8MSWIN1251'', ''CL8ISO8859P5'')) Name
```

На стороне MSSQL переведем это назад в строку:

```
CAST(Name AS VARCHAR(MAX))
```